# Like Uber Cream App we add geo fence area from admin, how we can block api request of restricted are area does not belong circle that is like map

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.8

We added geo fence from our admin [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMfmc.png)

we want to block this area from api book a ride request issue is mysql have only radius to check the lat long is not the area or not but we want to block like map wise area

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: we have radius fuction only like this to block request on ride i need polygon here